# Cannot purchase products in our published app on android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Our company implemented the In App Billing for Android, but we have a problem with purchases in a PUBLISHED app and their items just being PUBLISHED too.
When the user purchases a product, this message always appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZm9K.png

All documentation for this error, points at the items not being available to the publisher, or to the account, owner of the app.
We're seeking a fix since two weeks ago and we can't found a valid solution that works.

Before publish the application the test with android.test.purchased works fine.
We tested after publish with multiple android devices, and multiple accounts who bought products in another applications already published on the market.

Somebody knows about the possible causes of this error, or maybe how to fix it?